# How to use Cucumber ReTry Runner in Combination of cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-junit

I am using cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin, for generating dynamic runners on run-time for my Java-cucumber based tests.

```
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0</version>
```

For standalone tests we have something called ReTry Runner which can be triggered after finishing of the current Cucumber tests.

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"listners.ExtListner",
                "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
                "json:target/cucumber.json"}
        ,features = {"@target/rerun.txt"}
        , format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report-retry"}
        , glue = {"stepDefs"}
        ,strict = false
)
public class IOSReTryRunner {
    private static boolean dunit = false;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() throws IOException, AWTException {
        // Initiates the extent report and generates the output in the output/Run_<unique timestamp>/report.html file by default.
        ExtListner.initiateExtentCucumberFormatter();
        // Loads the extent config xml to customize on the report.
        ExtListner.loadConfig(new File("src/main/resources/features/extent-config.xml"));

        // User can add the system information as follows
        ExtListner.addSystemInfo("Browser Name", "<Name>");

        // Also you can add system information using a hash map
        Map systemInfo = new HashMap();
        systemInfo.put("Cucumber version", "v1.2.3");
        systemInfo.put("Extent Cucumber Reporter version", "v1.1.1");
        ExtListner.addSystemInfo(systemInfo);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown() throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException {
        System.out.println("Ran the tearDown.");
//        WebDriverFactory.getInstance().closeAppiumDriver();

    }
}
```

Is there any way that I could use the same mechanism for Auto-generated runners using above referred cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin` is a code generator. You can provide it with a custom virtual marker template through the `customVmTemplate` in the maven configuration.

For a reference of what is supported check the build in templates:

- [cucumber-junit-runner.java.vm](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/cucumber-junit-runner.java.vm)
- [cucumber-testng-runner.java.vm](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/cucumber-testng-runner.java.vm)

Comment: Thanks for providing brief pointer. To implement it fully, I need slightly more help. Normal cucumber-java runner creates a retry report in below OutPut directory "html:target/cucumber-html-report-retry" as in Cucumber options we add following: ". "rerun:target/rerun.txt"" Then using another runner (as referred in original question) I am able to run only failed cases. So, in case of parallel runner plugin, where how shall we aggregate failed tests. May be do you have sample code snippet? Many thanks